# How to add meta tags on custom paths in Drupal 8?

Tags: meta-tags, drupal-8

Does anybody know how can I add meta tags on custom paths in Drupal 8? I am using the [metatags](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can add any meta tag programmatically from your custom module using hook_page_attachments() as below.

```
function MYMODULE_page_attachments(array &$page) {
    $ogTitle = [
             '#tag' => 'meta',
             '#attributes' => [
                    'property' => 'og:title',
                    'content' => 'This is my page title',
                ],
            ];
    $page['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$ogTitle, 'og:title'];   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tested succesfuly [Metatag Routes](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag_routes) module for Drupal 8. The module adds a button in the default metatag dashboard page. The user can configure metatags for custom controllers generated by code.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to make it in a controller :

```
  public function index()
  {
    $variables = [];

    return [
      '#theme' => 'my_theme',
      '#variables' => $variables,
      '#attached' => [
        'library' => [
        ],
        // Added for open graph and SEO.
        'html_head' =>       
        [
            [
              '#tag' => 'meta',
              '#attributes' => [
                'name' => 'og:descritpion',
                'description' => 'My sublim description',
              ],
            ],
            'og:descritpion',
        ],
    ];
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

The only solution actually with metatag module for Drupal 8, is to use fields in your content type, and use them as metatag element with token possibilities.

It works well like that. I also wait for a better solution.